# Frequent JavaScript error which requires reinstall to resolve

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am frequently experiencing "A JavaScipt error occurred in the main process" and am unable to find a resolution except to reinstall, which does work.

Most recently this has occurred on version 1.38.1 on Windows 10, but it has been occurring regularly for the last 6 months or more.

This appears to happen with every Windows update (which our company does regularly), but I am not positive that it is the only factor. It happens roughly once/week, and it is not reproduced on Linux.

[image: Description]

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Have you considered to use a container like Docker? It could isolate your app from the environment.

Comment: @sirandy note that the error is caused by the program visual studio code, and not an application the OP made

Comment: Right! so the error is over the editor not in your app.

Comment: @sirandy I have not tried that, and it may very well be a good workaround for this problem; I can certainly try that. But it still is a problem that I hope receives some attention so that a workaround isn't necessary.